# Is there a way to freeze the world?

Tags: conan-exiles, nvidia-ansel

Since the multiplayer world I'm playing in runs on a server, 'pausing' the game or using any of the built-in admin functions (specifically 'Freeze time') will not prevent the world from remaining animated.

For screen archery purposes, I require everything to be temporarily put to a halt, including NPC animations, flora and fauna animations, weather, lighting, animated textures, decals, sprites, and what have you.

I'm using the [Nvidia Ansel](https://www.nvidia.com/en-gb/geforce/geforce-experience/ansel/) tool to make screenshots. One of its features is the super resolution screenshot, which renders the current screen space at higher resolution, or, practically, takes multiple contiguous screenshots at the current resolution and patches them together. But when there are any changes in animation or lighting, these will show up in the result (like a bad simulation of extended exposure time):

| [image] | [image] |
| --- | --- |

Conan: Exiles runs on Unreal Engine 4.
I tried the `FreezeRendering` command, but [apparently](https://forums.epicgames.com/udk/udk-development/ios-development/284803-freeze-rendering) it only works in the editor (and might not do what I want anyway).

I have access to admin tools on the server.

**Is there any way to completely freeze the game client-side or server-side?**

As "client-side" implies, it won't matter if the game itself actually continues, as long as the world as seen by me is completely still.